# What is is_admin function?

Tags: wordpress, web

A website says:-

> This Conditional Tag checks if the Dashboard or the administration panel is attempting to be displayed. It is a boolean function that will return true if the URL being accessed is in the admin section, or false for a front-end page.
>
> This function does not verify whether the current user has permission to view the Dashboard or the administration panel. Use current_user_can() instead.

And Some other Web says:-

> One way this bug creeps into WordPress applications is through a **common mistake WordPress developers** make where they use a function called ‘is_admin()’ to try to validate that someone is an administrator. Which may be use to Authentication bypass.

So my question is simple i.e Why the web developer do this mistake.? Is it compulsory to use this function.? And is there any alternative to use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_admin()` is not intended to be used for security checks. It will return true whenever the current URL is for a page on the admin side of WordPress. It does not check if the user is logged in, nor if the user even has access to the page being requested. It is a convenience function for plugins and themes to use for various purposes, but it is not suitable for validating secured requests.

You can use `current_user_can()` function to do the user validations and other similar function.